# IOS Firebase Dynamic Links with Test Flight

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a react native app. I've added firebase dynamic links. When I try my dynamic link I get redirected to the store and it says "App not available. This app is currently not available in your country or region".

My app is not on the store but it is in TestFlight. I am hoping to get it to redirect to TestFlight. Currently it is in internal testing in TestFlight and I am able to see the app myself if I open the TestFlight app.

The dynamic link looks like this:

```
https://servicebayrev.page.link/?link=https://joshua-deeplink.azurewebsites.net/servicebay?username%3Djoshua&apn=au.com.rev.servicebay.expo&isi=6443547220&ibi=au.com.rev.servicebay.expo
```

Is it possible to get it to work with TestFlight? Phone is ios 15.6

Comment: When installing your app via TestFlight, sometimes the 'apple-app-site-association' file is fetched by the device from your web site as soon as the app is installed, but every now and then (and I surely don't know why this is) the file is not fetch from your site until after a significant delay has transpired. Once as long as 15 minutes later. If you are able inspect your server logs, you might see this as well. I'm wondering if this is the case for everyone reporting the problem and if this symptom might make it easier to track down the root cause.

Comment: In this situation, the app is showing in TestFlight but I have deliberately not yet installed it. I am testing the workflow when the user has not yet installed the app. In production, this would mean getting redirected to the store. Not sure how to test this before going live though.